# Get originalTarget from tab load event MDN

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, firefox-addon

I'm trying get originalTarget DOM following this example :

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function(aEvent){ s.handleLoadBrowser(aEvent);},     true);

handleLoadBrowser : function (aEvent){
    var w = aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView;
}
```

I create an event listener for tab load:

```
var tab = gBrowser.addTab("www.google.com");
tab.addEventListener("load", function(aEvent){ s.handleLoadTab(aEvent) }, true);

handleLoadTab : function (aEvent){
    var w = aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView;
}
```

Here I get the error: "TypeError: win is undefined".

How could I get this dom object from tab event load ?

Comment: What is the actual, complete, error message including file and line number? The error you show states the variable `win` is undefined. The code you have provided does not contain a `win` variable. Thus, you have not included the code that is actually causing the error you are seeing. Please include the code that is actually causing the error. Note: code provided does not reflect the structure of your code because `s.handleLoadTab` is not `handleLoadTab`. We have to assume the `s` object. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first example, it should work: I did similar: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9287185#file-bootstrap-js-L98 my only difference is that i do: `gBrowser.addEventListener("load", s.handleLoadBrowser, true);`

Regarding the second example: `var tab = gBrowser.addTab("www.google.com");
tab.addEventListener("load", function(aEvent){ s.handleLoadTab(aEvent) }, true);` you cant do this, you dont add load events to tab, a tab is an xul element that you grab and move around. You can do `tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.addEventListener('load'` but after the first page load it will no longer be there.

This code works for me:

```
var tab = gBrowser.addTab("data:text/html,<b>hi</b>");
tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", handleLoadTab, true);
//tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleLoadTab, true);

function handleLoadTab(aEvent){
    var w = aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView;
  w.alert('load done')
}
```

Also here's another example of how to listen to the first on load of one tab. I use `gBrowser.loadOneTab` in this example, but its interchangeable with `addTab`: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f076070bc77abd5e406

```
var tab = gBrowser.loadOneTab('data:text/html,<span class="profilist-build-icon-1">backround of this span is of icon on desktop</span><input type="button" value="applyCss"><input type="button" value="removeCss"> Change File on Desktop to: <input type="button" value="Release Img"><input type="button" value="Beta Img"><input type="button" value="Aurora Img"><input type="button" value="Nightly Img">', {inBackground:false});
    var mobs = new window.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var attrVal = tab.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName);
            console.log(mutation.attributeName, attrVal);
            if (mutation.attributeName == 'progress' && attrVal == 'true') {
              //at this point can addEventListener for DOMConentLoaded and it will as document hasnt loaded yet
              tab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                tab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
                alert('loadOneTab finished loading', tab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML)
              }, false);
              mobs.disconnect();
            }
          /*
            if (mutation.attributeName == 'progress' && attrVal == '') {
             //cannot add addEventListener for DOMConentLoaded here as document is already loaded, it will never fire
              alert('tab done loading');
              mobs.disconnect();
            }
           */
        });
    });
    mobs.observe(tab, {
        attributes: true
    });

console.log(tab._fullyOpen)
```